# hadoop Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to get hadoop set up on my laptop.  I have followed a few tutorials on setting up hadoop.

I ran this command:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>
```

If I run it again it says already exists.

I try to run the test jar file with this command:

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

and receive this exception

`16/01/22 15:11:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/<username>/.staging/job_1453492366595_0006
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/<username>/grep-temp-891167560`

I did not realize that I receive this before this error:

```
16/01/22 15:51:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/22 15:51:51 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/01/22 15:51:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 33
16/01/22 15:51:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:33
16/01/22 15:51:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1453492366595_0009
16/01/22 15:51:52 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1453492366595_0009
16/01/22 15:51:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Marys-MacBook-Pro.local:8088/proxy/application_1453492366595_0009/
16/01/22 15:51:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1453492366595_0009
16/01/22 15:51:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1453492366595_0009 running in uber mode : false
16/01/22 15:51:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/01/22 15:51:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1453492366595_0009 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1453492366595_0009 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1453492366595_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://Marys-MacBook-Pro.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1453492366595_0009Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1453492366595_0009_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

There is a stack trace the follows this.
I am on a Mac PC.

Comment: What does that JAR file do? `grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'` are the arguments, so I assume it is running `grep` over the `input` directory/file for the pattern `dfs[a-z.]+` and putting the result into the `output` directory?

Comment: This is the example provided by several tutorials.  Your assumptions seem to be correct. I am following this site: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: Did you run the `bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input` that that link mentions?

Comment: Yes I had run that and ran it again.

Comment: I added more information to my question.

Comment: With exit code 127 - I was able to find out that I needed to run this command on OSX to make a link to /bin/java   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/java /bin/java

Comment: Is `<username>` the name of the directory you created?

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but I think will allow that. The problem may arise later with how different APIs will handle names with characters like angle brackets. A few examples: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3257, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-4821, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-240

Answer (score 2):

I use `Hadoop` 2.7.2, and While following [the Official Docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_Single_Node), I also encountered this problem at first.

The reason was that I forgot to follow  *"Prepare to Start the Hadoop Cluster"* chapter.

I solved it by setting `JAVA_HOME` in `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's because using wrong version JDK with hadoop. I used hadoop 2.6.5. At first, I started hadoop using oracle JDK 1.8.0_131, ran example jar and error occurred. After I used JDK 1.7.0_80, the example works like a charm.

There is a page about [HadoopJavaVersions](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions).